# Best approach to build a basic multi robot controller

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, multi-robot

I'm a beginner in ROS. I've 2 robots which run ROS Kinetic (Those robots are commercially available and I've access to the system). I've searched about the Multi robot control systems and found RMF, which has basically everything. But I want to grow up my knowledge and build a basic multi robot controller myself.

So far, this is what I've planned.

***Implement a central server (Linux with ROS kinetic?) (For path planning and traffic management. As for the start, I hope to navigate robots through a narrow hall, so in this case server should monitor and stop a one robot then continue the other robots navigation)

I understand that both robots must have the same map.

Is this a good approach? If so, how'd I get the planned path from the server and insert it to those robots, via what topics?